# Implement a C# Interface in F#

Tags: f#

I have the following interface in C#

```cs
public interface IDog
{
    String Bark();
}
```

I want to create an implementation in F#.  I had no problem with this:

```
type GermanShepherd() = 
        interface IDog with
            member this.Bark() = "Woof"
```

but when I added a supporting function that is not part of the interface like this:

```
type GermanShepherd() = 
        interface IDog with
            member this.Bark() = "Woof"
            member this.Eat() = "Yummy"
```

the compiler complained:

```
Error   1   No abstract or interface member was found that corresponds to this override 
Error   2   This value is not a function and cannot be applied*
```

Is there a way of implementing private/internal functions with a type that implements an interface without those functions being part of the interface?  I can't change the interface in my 'real' application b/c there are other projects that implement the interface.  None of the examples on MSDN that I found have this particular scenario.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The `interface` block should only contain functions that are part of the interface, but you can place other functions before the block:

```
type GermanShepherd() = 
    member this.Eat() = "Yummy" 
    interface IDog with
        member this.Bark() = "Woof"
```

If you do not need a public member, then you can go with a private let-bound function:

```
type GermanShepherd() = 
    let eat() = "Yummy" 
    interface IDog with
        member this.Bark() = "Woof"
```

Also note that F# currently only allows *explicit* interface implementations, which means that you can treat `GermanShepherd` as `IDog`, but you won't see `IDog` members explicitly:

```
let g = GermanShepherd()
g.Eat()            // OK
g.Bark()           // Error, interface members are implemented explicitly
let d = g :> IDog  // To 'Bark', we need to get 'IDog' first
d.Bark()           // OK
```

One workaround for this is to add the `Bark` method explicitly as a separate member *outside* of the `interface` block. Although there is [F# language issue](http://fslang.uservoice.com/forums/245727-f-language/suggestions/5669367-allow-implicit-interface-implementation) for this too!

Comment: That works and I will use it.  I do note that it violates the step-down rule where private/supporting functions go below the public functions.  Thanks!

Comment: You can put members after the interface block too, although this is not the case for private let bindings.

Comment: @JamieDixon In F#, private/supporting functions almost always go before public ones - if they are let-bound functions, they have to. Since the F# compiler works strictly top to bottom, the step-down rule can't really be applied to F# code.

Comment: Thanks for that.  I really have to force myself to forget C# idoms when using F#.